# htaccess rewriterule: redirect http to https or https to http (both ways) depending on URL typed

Tags: http, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, https

Could anybody please help me to write rewriterule, that redirects http<->https (back and force depending of URL typed) with these conditions:

1) `http://www.mydomain.com , http://www.mydomain.com/?p=home , http://www.mydomain.com/?p=home1 , http://www.mydomain.com/?qqq=home` are always http, even if https are typed instead of http.

2) all the rest pages are always https, even if http was typed instead of https.

The code below redirects all urls (and keeps parameters), except http://www.mydomain.com , to https.

```
#redirects http to https if there are parameters
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

I've tried to add the code below right after the code above to redirect https to http as well (if there are no parametres), so that all pages are always https, except www.mydomain.com, but I had no luck. Also I missed ?p=home, ?p=home1, ?qqq=home - I don't know how to add them.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP} off
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding the following to your htaccess file  in the root directory of your site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#determine if page is supposed to be http
#if it has p=home or p=home1 or qqq=home in querystring
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)(p=home1?|qqq=home)(&|$) [NC,OR]
#or if query string is empty
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
#set env var to 1
RewriteRule ^ - [E=IS_HTTP:1]


#all pages that are supposed to be http redirected if https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{ENV:IS_HTTP} 1
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L=301]

#all other pages are sent to https if not already so
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{ENV:IS_HTTP} !1
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L=301]
```

Comment: Wow... Seems like I understand the principle but I would never write it on my own from the scratch. How can people answer my question in less that a year?..:) Another question is: Could you please explain "home1?". Does it mean "home1" or "home1" with the last symbol ("1") voided? Thank you.   And the second question: [E=IS_HTTP:1] or [ENV=IS_HTTP:1]? Thank you.

Comment: @Haradzieniec `home1?` matches `home` or `home1` i.e. the `?` makes the `1` optional. `E` or `env` will work.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works, but.... I don't know if that's a question for this topic, not for another one... With your code, https is in red and crossed out in Chrome and similar error happens in FF. Once I remove your code, everything is OK, the SSL certificate is displayed fine - it's green. It even works fine with the first and the third block of your code (but without the second block, that starts with "RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on"). What could be the reason? Thank you very much.

Comment: The problem regarding crossed https in Chrome is here: pictures are in the folder. Regarding the rewritecond suggested by Ulrich Palha (and he's right), pictures from the folder will always be loaded via http. That's why https page has errors.